# .deps/*.Po: No such file or directory compiler error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autoconf

My configure.ac looks like

```
AC_PREREQ(2.61)
AC_INIT(MyProject, 1.0.0, BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.10 no-define foreign])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR(configure.ac)
AC_CONFIG_HEADER([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([obj/threading/Makefile])
#AC_OUTPUT([Makefile obj/Makefile obj/threading/Makefile])

AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PROG_CXX([clang++ g++])

AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11()
AS_IF([test "x$HAVE_CXX11" != "x1"],
      [AC_MSG_ERROR([** A compiler with C++11 language features is required.])])

CXXFLAGS='-Wall -std=c++11'
AC_SUBST(CXXFLAGS)

AC_OUTPUT
```

My Makefile.am looks like

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

SRCDIR = $(top_srcdir)/src/threading

bin_PROGRAMS = node                 

node_SOURCES  = $(SRCDIR)/UnitTests/node.cpp
node_CPPFLAGS = 
node_LDFLAGS  = 
node_CXXFLAGS = $( CXXFLAGS )
```

I get following error

```
Makefile:394: ../../src/threading/UnitTests/.deps/node-node.Po: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem with my autoconf files when I upgraded my autoconf version. I noticed there is a bug report on the Debian list: Bug [#752993](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1232579.html) that seems related to this problem. So, it seems that we've hit a bug in the autoconf project.

I've followed the workaround in the bug-report and that worked well for me. So, it meant that I removed the "AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects" in the Makefile.am. After doing that, I got lots of warnings on autoreconf, but it does work afterwards. So, you might want to try that out. Hope it helps you forward (after 9 months!)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem got it resolved by calling autoreconf -if in the project root directory

```
Makefile:577: .deps/testAll-bar_test.Po: No such file or directory
Makefile:579: .deps/testAll-main_testall.Po: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '.deps/testAll-main_testall.Po'.  Stop.

autoreconf -if
./configure
make # no more problem
```

I am using gtest for my C++ project.  The Makefile.am file is straightforward, nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

In Makefile.am, try the following. The "no-dependencies" setting will prevent the .deps/ folder and .Po files from being created.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects no-dependencies
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Dependencies.html